# Can not set text2 to milliuntilfinish in kotlin ... valueof is showing error

Tags: kotlin

object:CountDownTimer(30100, 1000)
 {
            override fun onFinish() {

```
            text2.setText("0s")
            text5.setText("Your Score:" + (Integer.toString(score)+ "/" + Integer.toString(noq)))
            playa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

        }

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            text2.setText(String.valueof(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "s")
}
```

}.start()

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Also can you please format your code snippet correctly? Also, there is no `String.valueOf` in kotlin

Comment: sry for inconvenience im new to kotlin.... can u tell me what i should use instead string.valueof to set my text2 to timer....and sry for that i dont know how to format my code snippet correctly... but i can sent u my full code...

Comment: i am basically trying to make brain trainer app... i need 30s countdown timer for it.... i am basically watching android development in java and trying to convert it in kotln but app is not working though i convert it fully

Comment: If all you need is to convert the `millisUntilFinished` value to seconds text, you can do `text2.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000).toString().plus("s"))`

Comment: bro can u help me with some code ..... just for one time.... i maneged to write code but app is always crashing and i dont know what is the problem

Comment: what help do you need?